# Comparison operator performance <= against !=

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, performance, operators

Lets start out with stating code-readability beats micro-optimizations and we should rather leave that to the compiler. This was just a weird case where the specifics seemed interesting against general recommendation

So was messing about with a Prime number generator function, and came up with a weird behavior where "!=" which people recommend to be the most efficient actually the least efficient and "<=" which is the worst as the best option.

**C#**

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {
  long totalTicks = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    PrintPrimes(15000);
    totalTicks += stopWatch.ElapsedTicks;
  }
  Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\nTick Average: {0}", totalTicks / 100);
  Console.Read();
}

private static void PrintPrimes(int numberRequired) {
  if (numberRequired < 1)
    return;
  Console.Write("{0}\t", 2);
  int primeTest = 3;
  /****** UPDATE NEXT TWO LINES TO TEST FOR != *****/
  int numPrimes = 2;  // set numPrimes = 1 for !=
  while (numPrimes <= numberRequired) {  // switch <= to !=
    if (IsPrime(primeTest)) {
      Console.Write("{0}\t", primeTest);
      ++numPrimes;
    }
    primeTest += 2;
  }
}

private static bool IsPrime(int test) {
  for (int i = 3; i * i <= test; i = 2 + i)
    if (test % i == 0)
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Output:

```
<= 1319991
!= 1321251
```

**Similarly In C++(On a different machine)**

```
include <cstddef>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  for(size_t i(0) ; i <= 10000000000 ; ++i);
}
```

Output:

```
<=

real        0m16.538s
user        0m16.460s
sys        0m0.000s
~ [master] $ vim d.cc

!=

real        0m16.860s
user        0m16.780s
sys        0m0.000s
```

The loops run the same amount of times. Are there any optimizations for `<=` which does not apply for `!=` or is it some weird cpu behavior?

Comment: The C# and the C++ programs are not doing the same things, you can not compare them! You also have to take into account what other things the computer runs in the background while your program is running, if a heave process runs then your process will also be slower.

Comment: actually I did run a similar clone with prime number generation on c++ which gave the same output behavior as well. I was ust trying to show this cos it did not seem to do with some weirdness in prime number generation. I'll add the other c++ code too

Comment: What you should to is first make sure the C# and the C++ programs are doing the same things. Then the runtime environment is the same during all runs of the programs. And then run all programs multiple times, and average the times before before doing any type of conclusions.

Comment: I see no difference in performance. Do you know about [random variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variation) and [significance testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_testing)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Though the C# and C++ programs are indeed different, nobody (except you) seems to be comparing them.  He is comparing `!=` to `<` in C#, and he's comparing `!=` to `<` in C++.  I don't see a comparison between C# and C++ in any way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't make sense that there would be a difference, assuming the result is the same number of iterations.

If we assume it's an x86 processor, `!=` turns into `jne` (or `je`, depending on which side of the "it is" or "it is not" jumps [1]). A `<=` will do `jle` or `jgt` depending on which way the loop goes. Whilst the instructions are different, other processors have the same sort of instructions.

I suspect you have measurement errors. A difference of less than 0.2 seconds out of 16s is not a huge difference, and you may simply have had a few more network packets, hard disk interrupts or some background process running that time.

[1] A `for` loop that has a fixed set of iterations, for example, will typically just have a "if  not true, jump to beginning of loop", and the same applies to `while` loops.

I just ran this on my machine:

```
bool IsPrime(int test) {
  for (int i = 3; i * i <= test; i = 2 + i)
    if (test % i == 0)
      return false;
  return true;
}

void PrintPrimes(int numberRequired) {
  if (numberRequired < 1)
    return;
  int primeTest = 3;
  /****** UPDATE NEXT TWO LINES TO TEST FOR != *****/
  int numPrimes = 2;  // set numPrimes = 1 for !=
  while (numPrimes != numberRequired) {  // switch <= to !=
    if (IsPrime(primeTest)) {
      ++numPrimes;
    }
    primeTest += 2;
  }
}

int  main() 
{
  long totalTicks = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    PrintPrimes(15000);
  }
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -O3 primes.cpp`. The difference between using `!=` and `<=` in the main loop is not noticeable. The fastest time for `!=` is 3.326s, for `<=` 3.329, the slowest for `!=` is 3.332 and with `<=` it is 3.335s. Having run many benchmarks on my machine before, I know that there is no significance in the millisecond digit, so I would say that it takes 3.33 seconds for both.

And just to confirm:

```
--- primesne.s  2013-04-30 23:52:10.840513380 +0100
+++ primesle.s  2013-04-30 23:52:35.457639603 +0100
@@ -46,7 +46,7 @@
 .L3:
    addl    $2, %esi
    cmpl    $15000, %edi
-   jne .L10
+   jle .L10
    subl    $1, %r9d
    jne .L2
    xorl    %eax, %eax
```

The entire difference between the "not equal" and "less or equal" is the `jne` vs `jle` instructions - this is the assembler output from `g++` of the two variants of the code - and that is the ENTIRE output from `diff`.

Comment: Think that's as clear as it gets. Makes sense there is no actual difference between either operators and ust a case of error in the calculation of timespan due to some random operations on the machine

Comment: Just to confirm, I've added the assembler output from the compiler as well.